# How to send POST data in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I need to write a script that receives and parses a JSON array within the POST array.  In order to do this, I'm first trying to just send any old JSON data to my script so I have something to work with.

My receiving script is in PHP (but alternately could be done in Javascript.)  Right now, I'm just serializing the POST array and writing it to a text file to make sure something is coming in.  What it's writing is an empty array, though.

I'm trying to send the data using an ajax request.  This is what I have at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
        var jsondata = JSON.stringify({
            val1:"this",
            val2:"that"
        });  

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.mydomain.com/test/index.php",
            method: "POST",        
            data: {json: jsondata},
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));},
            error: function(errMsg) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(errMsg));
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried lots of variations on this, too, including

- not stringifying jsondata
- changing data to this: `data: jsondata`
- using `type:` instead of `method:`in the request
- including `datatype: "json"` in the request

and some other variations I can't even remember at this point.  Am I missing something simple?  Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

EDIT: adding my index.php file

```
if (isset($_POST)){
    // This line is commented out because it breaks it.
    //$jspost = json_decode($_POST['json']);
    $jsser = serialize($_POST);
    echo "I'm here.";
    // Write to text file
    $myfile = "response.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $now = date("n/j/y g:i:s a");
    fwrite($fh, $now."\r\n");
    fwrite($fh, "I received a POST.\r\n");
    fwrite($fh, $jsser);
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n\n");
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: What does `JSON.stringify(data)` output in your success callback?

Comment: Can we see the content of your index.php file? A good strategy is to do vardumps and die() in the php script to be sure is not a server side error. If not, console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) to check the response.

Comment: The output of JSON.stringify(data) in the success callback is, "I'm here.", which is echoed from the index.php file.

Comment: I figured it out!  It was my contentType.  When I set it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" instead of "application/json", then var_dump on index.php showed the values of jsondata coming through.

Answer (score 7):

**JS**

Send a JSON String

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var obj = {
            val1: "this",
            val2: "that"
        };
        obj.val3 = 'these';
        obj['val4'] = 'those';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "service.php",
            data: {
                 json: JSON.stringify(obj)
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //service.php response
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

**service.php**

Decode and work the received object

```
$json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json');
$decoded_json = json_decode($json);
$val1 = $decoded_json->val1;

var_dump($decoded_json, $val1);
```

Viceversa, if you want to send a JSON from php and decode it into JS

**PHP**

```
$responseArray = array();
$responseArray['key1'] = 'value1';
$responseArray['key2'] = 'value2';

echo json_encode($responseArray);
```

**JS**

```
success: function (response) {
    var decodedJson = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(decodedJson['key1']);
}
```

Comment: I'd give this a vote if I could (not enough reputation points) because it had a lot of useful information that ultimately led to me figuring out that contentType was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... I was not using a form but rather data variables collected from the element. I tried the previous methods and did not get a result.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var jsondata = new FormData();
    jsondata.append("val1", "this");
    jsondata.append("val2", "that");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.mydomain.com/test/index.php",
        method: "POST",        
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));},
        error: function(errMsg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(errMsg));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var jsondata = {
        "val1":"this",
        "val2":"that"
    };  

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.mydomain.com/test/index.php",
        method: "POST",        
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "json",
        success: function(data){
           //your success function
        },
        error: function(errMsg) {
            //your error function
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried that but am still seeing an empty array when I serialize POST and write it to response.txt.